# System time changes after sleeping and waking up?

Tags: time

Closing the lid to sleep, after waking, the system time would change by as much as 2 seconds.

Verified by using terminal command for over a month, daily
sudo -S ntpdate -u time.apple.com

Comment: 2 second drive for a week of sleep wouldn’t be odd. 5 minutes, perhaps more rare. What do you want to do / know?

Comment: I want to know why the time changes at all?

Comment: It would be best to ask why explicitly in the body of the question if that's what you seek to get an answered.

Comment: Why is a "2 second drive for a week of sleep" not odd? What is the mechanism behind that?

Comment: I should rephrased: "I want to know why the time changes at all when sleeping and waking"

Answer (score 1):

Seems fairly normal, probably just checking back in with Apple servers about the time (time.apple.com) If you'd like to disable it, you can uncheck "Set date and time automatically" under Date and Time in System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: I have that option checked, how often does the auto update occur and do any specific events cause to to update by itself?

Comment: @ssj I'm not sure.